# How can i get the changing environment variable in perl

Tags: perl

In my perl script, i want to get the environment variable to my perl variable. I can do this

```
$no_of_lic = $ENV{`ON_OF_ENV`};
```

but this is working only for the first time if the environment variable changes in the same shell script then it will not take the updated value.

my code :

```
!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

$no_of_lic = $ARGV[0]; 

$ENV{'NO_OF_LIC'} = $no_of_lic;

print "No of lic to be picked : $no_of_lic\n";

print "Environment var : $ENV{NO_OF_LIC}\n";

sleep(1);

while ($no_of_lic != 0) {

  sleep(1);

  print "no of lic : $no_of_lic\n";

  #$no_of_lic = $ENV{'NO_OF_LIC'};

  sleep(10);

}
```

while the script is running in the backgorund i will change the environment variable 
`setenv $NO_OF_ENV 5`

Once i do this, i am expecting that the script will print with updated values as 5

but its not happening .. can any one tell how to do this?

Comment: Programs are given their environment when they start.  Modifying the environment in the parent (or any other process) does not update the child process' environment.  If you need to communicate with the program, consider using a file (reading it each time in the loop) or some other IPC mechanism (sockets, a database, etc).

Comment: @KyleBurton: Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Done, but there are already other answers...Thanks @Borodin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That isn't how environment variables work.

When your Perl script is launched, it gets a clone of your shell's environment. After that, while the Perl script is running, any changes to your shell's environment will not be seen in Perl's copy of the environment. (And any changes to your Perl's environment will not be seen by your shell.)

This is not specific to Perl - all scripting languages will behave the same in this regard. It's just how the environment is implemented in Unix. (And I believe Windows implements them similarly.)

If you need to send new data to a Perl script which is running in the background, investigate options such as FIFOs (a.k.a. "named pipes"), or sockets (e.g. TCP sockets). The wider term for this concept is inter-process communication (IPC), and the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) section of perldoc has plenty more information on the topic.

Comment: Thanks tobyink .. do u have any example to work out this through IPC

Answer (score 6):

Child processes will get a copy of all variables from their parent process. Later changes of variables of the parent process will not be reflected in its child processes.

Think about it: if you change the working directory of a process and it would change the working directory of all its child processes (and in turn their children) that would be … very inconvenient (to put it mildly).

Answer (score 2):

Programs are given their environment when they start. Modifying the environment in the parent (or any other process) does not update the child process' environment. If you need to communicate with the program, consider using a file (reading it each time in the loop) or some other IPC mechanism (sockets, a database, etc).

Comment: can u elaborate on how i can use IPC ?